# Transfer Device Enrollment from one Mac to another

Tags: macos, mobile-device-management, configuration-profiles, automated-device-enrollment

I enrolled my private MBP with my employer's Intune Company Portal and got access to company resources.

Now they changed the policy and private MacBooks are no longer allowed to be be enrolled. That wasn't a problem for me since my old MBP is already enrolled and worked fine, but now I've decided to replace it.

Is there any possibility to transfer data to a new Mac including all of the enrolment profiles and certificates so it just continues working like if it was the "old" one?

Answer (score 2):

That is not very likely. Usually part of the "recognition" involves the physical identity of the machine.

However, if you test it and it works you may be lucky.

BUT, note that if you do "test" it then the recognition process may notice 2 different machines and block both.